# Php script loop 5 times then die

Tags: php

How to have this part of my php file (that queries my dbase), run 5 times then stop if condition stays false after the 5th attempt?

Here is the part of my file I want to loop :

```
 if ((isset($_POST['_Commandeviapaypal'])) && ($PaypalStatus != "Completed"))
 {
 sleep(60);
 $PaypalPayment = "SELECT payment_amt FROM al_paypal WHERE ((item_number='" .$No . "') || (item_number='" .$NoGift . "'))   ";
 $query1 = mysql_query($PaypalPayment);
 $row1 = mysql_fetch_row($query1);
 $PaypalPayment = $row1[0];
 $PaypalConfirmation = "SELECT txn_id FROM al_paypal WHERE ((item_number='" .$No . "') || (item_number='" .$NoGift . "')) ";
 $query2 = mysql_query($PaypalConfirmation);
 $row2 = mysql_fetch_row($query2);
 $PaypalConfirmation = $row2[0];
 $PaypalStatus = "SELECT payment_status FROM al_paypal WHERE ((item_number='" .$No . "') ||  (item_number='" .$NoGift . "')) ";
 $query3 = mysql_query($PaypalStatus);
 $row3 = mysql_fetch_row($query3);
 $PaypalStatus = $row3[0]; 
 }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why are doing this ? Why 3 requests to get the same row in your database ?

Comment: You realise that most web servers like apache have a timeout, typically defaulting to 5 minutes, and you sleep for 60 seconds each iteration of your loop: 5 * 60 seconds = 5 minutes... coincidence? I think not

Comment: Use a `for` loop. If the query is successful, set a variable that says it was successful, and use `break` to exit the loop.

Comment: Vincent not the same row.

Comment: Mark so I do not need the Die(), thanks.

Comment: Same table and same condition, it's the same row. But you get 3 differents columns.

Comment: Vincent, I am not a programmer. If it can be simplified, I am happy to learn! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop to iterate 5 times, with an additional condition in the loop, like so:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5 && (CONDITION); ++$i) {
    //Code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable that keeps track of how many attempts you've made so far, and stop looping when you reach 5.

```
if ((isset($_POST['_Commandeviapaypal'])) && ($PaypalStatus != "Completed"))
{
    $attempts = 0;
    while ($attempts < 5)
    {
        // other code
        if (/* successful */)
        {
            break;
        }

        $attempts = $attemps + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Loop, not condition. It should be a `while`.

Comment: Yeah just realized that. Should be better now.